# How to select all fields in multi-select on single click in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, multiselect-attribute

I am working in magento 1.9 . I am making a muliselect field. I want to select all fields on single click . Did magento 1.9 gave such tag by default ? .
My code in system.xml looks like .

```
<serviceOptions>
    <label>Domestic Services </label>
    <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
    <source_model>FedExSmall/Source_FedExSmallServices</source_model>
    <sort_order>12</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</serviceOptions>
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: This type of feature is not related to magento. This feature is with html elements.

Comment: Dear by using Jquery i am achieving that target already . I am looking for some tag (if available in magento) OR i wish magento should support it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with xml, js

1. Add checkbox input after your `<serviceOptions>` node like this:

   ```
   <checkall translate="label">
       <label>Check all services</label>
       <class>Check-all-services</class>
       <frontend_type>checkbox</frontend_type>
       <sort_order>13</sort_order>
       <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
       <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
       <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
   </checkall>
   ```
2. You add this **js** code in your js admin

   ```
   $('#sd_general_general_checkall').click(function() {
       if($('#sd_general_general_checkall').is(":checked")) {
           $('#sd_general_general_serviceOptions option').prop('selected', true);
       } else {
           $('#sd_general_general_serviceOptions option').prop('selected', false);
       }
   });
   ```
3. Just if you haven't an admin js, you can it like this:

   **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/local.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <layout version="0.1.0">
       <adminhtml_system_config_edit>
           <reference name="head">
               <action method="addJs"><script>admin/my-custom-admin.js</script></action>
           </reference>
       </adminhtml_system_config_edit>
   </layout>
   ```
4. **js/admin/my-custom-admin.js**

   ```
   //put the content of the setp 2
   ```

**Important:** In step 2 you have to change the id's `#sd_general_general_checkall`, `#sd_general_general_serviceOptions` with the yours. if you encounter difficulties, post your full xml.